# Create Datetime from year and month hidden in multi-index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multi-index, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe where year and month are hidden in the `multi-index`. I want to create a datetime index as additional column (or separate series with same index).

```
                                           price            
                                            mean     mom_2  
foo          bar              year month                                      
997182819645 11               2010 1      1.1900  3.000000  
                                   2      2.2625  4.001769
```

I thought of adding the two levels of indices together as strings, and then read in that sequence into `pd.to_datetime()`. However, adding the two indices, I faced problems. I can add them up as integers just fine, but if I want to add them up as strings, I face some error:

```
In[193]: df.index.get_level_values('year').values.astype(str)
Out[193]: 

array(['2010', '2010', '2010', ..., '2014', '2014', '2014'], 
      dtype='<U21')
In[194]: df.index.get_level_values('month').values.astype(str)
Out[194]: 

array(['1', '2', '3', ..., '10', '11', '12'], 
      dtype='<U21')
In[195]: df.index.get_level_values('month').values.astype(str) + df.index.get_level_values('year').values.astype(str)

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types
 dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
```

How can I add create the datetime index here?

Comment: can you try without the call to `.values`: `df.index.get_level_values('month').astype(str) + df.index.get_level_values('year').astype(str)`

Comment: @EdChum That gave me `pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`, which is why I tried the values instaed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), but first need multiple `year` and `month` values:

```
y = df.index.get_level_values('year')
m = df.index.get_level_values('month')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(y * 10000 + m * 100 + 1, format="%Y%m%d")
print (df)
                              price                 Date
                                foo       bar           
foo          bar year month                             
997182819645 11  2010 1      1.1900  3.000000 2010-01-01
                      2      2.2625  4.001769 2010-02-01
```

If need then append column to `index`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(y * 10000 + m * 100 + 1, format="%Y%m%d")
df.set_index('Date', append=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
                                         price          
                                           foo       bar
foo          bar year month Date                        
997182819645 11  2010 1     2010-01-01  1.1900  3.000000
                      2     2010-02-01  2.2625  4.001769
```

---

Another solution with creating new `DataFrame`, but need last [0.18.1 version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0181-enhancements-assembling):

```
y = df.index.get_level_values('year')
m = df.index.get_level_values('month')
d = pd.Index(len(df.index) * [1], name='day')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year':y, 'month':m, 'day':d}, index=df.index)

df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df1)
print (df)
                              price                 Date
                                foo       bar           
foo          bar year month                             
997182819645 11  2010 1      1.1900  3.000000 2010-01-01
                      2      2.2625  4.001769 2010-02-01
```